# Writing to file function and performances

Tags: c++, file-io

When calling my write function, the compiler will see the file needs to stay open, right? Or will the file be opened and closed each time I call the function? Also, is my file closed at the end, even without explicitly closing it?
Is this the best way to handle writing to the same file?

```
void write(const std::string &filename, const std::string &text)
{
    std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );
    file << text << std::endl;
}

void write2(std::ofstream &file, const std::string &text)
{
    file << text << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int count(0);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        // Do heavy computing ...
        ++count;

        std::ostringstream out; out << count;
        write("test", out.str());
    }

    // Alternative

    std::ofstream file("test", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );

    count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        // Do heavy computing ...
        ++count;

        std::ostringstream out; out << count;
        write2(file, out.str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::ofstream file` will close in its destructor, at the end of `write` (or earlier if it exits via an exception). So the file will be opened and closed every iteration of the loop.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream

Perhaps you could make a little wrapper class that will contain the file, and has a `write` member function, or change `write` to take a `std::ofstream&`, which you create above the loop.

Comment: I see. So the write2 alternative is the canonical way to do it then ? No downside to keep the file opened for the whole time?

Comment: @user2287453 Yes. Also worth noting that `<< std::endl` is equivalent to `<< '\n' << std::flush`. Do you really need to flush the stream every time? If not, just use `<< '\n'`.

Comment: Doesn't it need at least one flush at the end ? Maybe it's always flushed before closing. Anyway, thanks very much for your help !

Comment: @user2287453 Yes, the underlying file buffer is flushed when it is closed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/close

Comment: An example of a time when you might want deliberate flushing all the time is writing to a log file, when you really do want the output to be instant. Note that there is usually some sensible flushing by default (say after a certain number of characters). Also, `std::cin` and `std::cout` are tied together, so using `cin` automatically first flushes `cout`. A stream might also have [`unitbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) set, so will flush after every output operation.

Comment: I only need to access the file once the program is done, so "\n" is useful for me here. Thanks for the added info.